# When upgrading to Yosemite from Mavericks are there any traps with Brew and Ports

Tags: macos, upgrade, homebrew, macports

Currently running Mavericks. Got a LOT of things installed through Homebrew and a handful through Ports. Are these going to survive the upgrade? What is best practice in this situation?

Comment: I did it without concerns. No problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of stuff installed in /usr/local, the upgrade will be extremely slow. It's faster to move it away before upgrading and move it back when the upgrade is done -- see [here](https://jimlindley.com/blog/yosemite-upgrade-homebrew-tips/) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

For MacPorts I can say that the only problem was to re-install MacPorts from source. Ports are running fine and I have a lot.
Now the package installer are avaiable:

- https://www.macports.org/install.php

  - https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.2-10.10-Yosemite.pkg